# How to perform a recursive filter search with QSortFilterProxyModel in QT 5.6.1?

Tags: python, maya, pyside2

I am working with QSortFilterProxyModel and I am looking for a solution to perform a recursive search in Qt Version: 5.6.1 in a QTreeView.

Since setRecursiveFilteringEnabled is added in a later version of QT I am able to used the method setRecursiveFilteringEnabled

I am currently using:

- PySide2 Version: 2.0.0~alpha0
- PySide2 Qt Version: 5.6.1  <--- setRecursiveFilteringEnabled was added later

How do I filter the entire hierarchy as I cannot use setRecursiveFilteringEnabled?

```py
from PySide2 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets

class MainFrame(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(parent)

        tree = {
            "Root": {
                "Level1": {
                    "Level1_item1": 14,
                    "Level1_item2": 12,
                    "Level1_item3": 3.55,
                },
                "Level2": {
                    "Level2_SubLevel1": {
                        "Level2_SubLevel1_item1": 3.52,
                        "Level2_SubLevel1_item2": 2.55,
                        "Level2_SubLevel1_item3": 13,
                    },
                    "Level2_SubLevel2": {
                        "Level2_SubLevel2_item1": 2,
                        "Level2_SubLevel2_item2": 4,
                        "Level2_SubLevel2_item3": 3.11,
                    },
                },
                "Level3": {
                    "Level3_item1": 12,
                    "Level3_item2": 13.55,
                    "Level3_item3": 122,
                },
            
            },
        }

        self.tree = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.filterEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.filterEdit.textChanged.connect(self.onTextChanged)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.filterEdit)
        layout.addWidget(self.tree)

        self.root_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.root_model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Level", "Values"])
        self.fill_model_from_json(self.root_model.invisibleRootItem(), tree)

        self.proxyModel = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
        self.proxyModel.setFilterKeyColumn(0)
        # Following call is not available in QT 5.6.1
        # self.proxyModel.setRecursiveFilteringEnabled(True) 
        
        self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(self.root_model)

        self.tree.setModel(self.proxyModel)
        self.tree.header().setMinimumSectionSize(300)

        self.tree.expandAll()
        self.resize(640, 480)

    def onTextChanged(self, text):
        self.proxyModel.setFilterRegExp(text)
        self.tree.expandAll()

    def fill_model_from_json(self, parent, d):
        if isinstance(d, dict):
            for key, value in d.items():
                it = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(key))
                if isinstance(value, dict):
                    parent.appendRow(it)
                    self.fill_model_from_json(it, value)
                else:
                    it2 = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(value))
                    parent.appendRow([it, it2])


d = MainFrame()
d.show()

# if __name__ == "__main__":
#     import sys

#     app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#     main = MainFrame()
#     main.show()
#     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The recursiveFilteringEnabled property was introduced in Qt 5.10

Comment: I am aware of when the property was introduced. Hence needing a workaround. I used print(PySide2.QtCore.__version__) to get the version. Thanks

Comment: If an older version was used to compile Qt (which you can get by running  `from PySide2.QtCore import qVersion` `print('Qt version', qVersion())`) and it is lower than Qt 5.10 then there is no workaround, so there are only 2 solutions: update pyside2 or implement the logic of that property.

Comment: I pointed out because your comment is confusing, you say that you know that recursiveFilteringEnabled exists for **Qt >= 5.10** (according to your comment) but in your post you point out: *PySide2 **Qt Version: 5.6.1** <--- setRecursiveFilteringEnabled should exists according to the docs.*

Comment: Yeah, I miss read the version. I will correct the post. I am not able to update pySide2. I am working within Maya